# Mockito: Can't mock method called on object

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm not allowed to post real code, but this is basically what's going on:

- We have a class `InterfaceOneImpl` that implements an interface `InterfaceOne` and a `InterfaceTwoImpl` that implements an `InterfaceTwo`
- `InterfaceTwoImpl` gets instantiated in `InterfaceOneImpl`, and `InterfaceTwoImpl.makeHttpRequest()` gets called, but I need to mock this function in my unit tests because I obviously don't want to make http requests in them. `makeHttpRequest` is a public, non-static function that returns a String

My code does something like this:

```
public class InterfaceOneImpl implements InterfaceOne{
    public String processRequest(...){
        ...
        InterfaceTwo obj = new InterfaceTwoImpl();
        obj.makeHttpRequest();
        ...
    }
}
```

My test class looks like this:

```
public TestInterfaceOneImpl {
    ....
    @Test
    public void testProcessRequest(){
        InterfaceOne interfaceOneImpl = new InterfaceOneImpl();
        InterfaceTwo mock = PowerMockito.mock(InterfaceTwoImpl.class);
        InterfaceTwo.when(mock.processRequest()).thenReturn("zzzz");
PowerMockito.whenNew(RiskValidationRestClientImpl.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn((RiskValidationRestClientImpl) mock);
        String reqStr = interfaceOneImpl.processRequest();
        
        //a bunch of failed assertions
    }
}
```

My issue is that processRequest() is not being mocked properly, because the source code version of the method is actually being run rather than the mock. When I step through each line of my unit test in debug mode, I always end up in the body of the makeHttpRequest() function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Consider refactoring your code to use dependency injection, so that you can avoid PowerMockito.

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is that processRequest() is not being mocked properly, because the source code version of the method is actually being run rather than the mock. When I step through each line of my unit test in debug mode, I always end up in the body of the makeHttpRequest() function.

I think your question is wrong - `processRequest`, based on your example, is a method on `InterfaceOne` while `mock` is an instance of `InterfaceTwo`.

I assume you meant:

```
InterfaceTwo.when(mock.makeHttpRequest()).thenReturn("zzzz");
```

In any case ...

```
What am I doing wrong?
```

You think you're mocking something when you're not at all. Let's break down your example:

```
// First you create an instance of InterfaceOneImpl - OK
InterfaceOne interfaceOneImpl = new InterfaceOneImpl();

// Next you create a mock of InterfaceTwo (I think? I don't use PowerMock) - OK
InterfaceTwo mock = PowerMockito.mock(InterfaceTwoImpl.class);

// Then you tell the mock you created that it should return "zzzz" - OK
InterfaceTwo.when(mock.processRequest()).thenReturn("zzzz");

// Finally you call a method on your instance. YOU DO NOT USE "mock" in
// any way shape or form. As it's defined, "processRequest" creates a NEW
// instance of InterfaceTwo: InterfaceTwo obj = new InterfaceTwoImpl();
// and uses THAT instance. So of course you will always end up with the
// real method being called. You're creating a mock and literally never
// using it.
String reqStr = interfaceOneImpl.processRequest();
```

To fix: actually use your mock. Either by passing it in the function:

```
// Pass the object to use as an argument
public String processRequest(InterfaceTwo obj){
    ...
    obj.makeHttpRequest();
    ...
}

// And then your test:
@Test
public void testProcessRequest() {
    InterfaceOne interfaceOneImpl = new InterfaceOneImpl();
    InterfaceTwo mock = PowerMockito.mock(InterfaceTwoImpl.class);
    InterfaceTwo.when(mock.processRequest()).thenReturn("zzzz");

    // NOW you can use the mock
    String reqStr = interfaceOneImpl.processRequest(mock);
}
```

Or by passing it through to the class:

```
public class InterfaceOneImpl implements InterfaceOne {

public InterfaceOneImpl(InterfaceTwo obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
}

public String processRequest(...){
        ...
        obj.makeHttpRequest();
        ...
    }
}

// And then your test
@Test
public void testProcessRequest(){
    InterfaceTwo mock = PowerMockito.mock(InterfaceTwoImpl.class);
    InterfaceTwo.when(mock.processRequest()).thenReturn("zzzz");

    // Now interface one will use the mock to do the request
    InterfaceOne interfaceOneImpl = new InterfaceOneImpl(mock);
    String reqStr = interfaceOneImpl.processRequest();
    
    //a bunch of failed assertions
}
```